# How does wep api return a content type of html although I have only defined a JsonFormatter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my Application_Start:

```
var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
```

My default url:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/")]
public HttpResponseMessage Index()
{
    var stream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Views\Home\Index.html"));
    var content = new StreamContent(stream);
    return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = content };
}
```

The content is of type `"text/html"` but I have not set it in the `response.Headers.ContentType` but still the html file is correctly returned although there is not something like a html content negotiator and actually I assumed the action would return the html file as json or an error would occur but everything worked fine.

Why is that?

Comment: Right, based on your above code I would expect the response content-type to be `application/octet-stream`..are you sure you are seeing response `Content-Type` header to be `text/html`?

Comment: the response.Headers collection is empty there is no content-type set explicitly. Thats the reason why I ask how is the file returned as HTML and not as json/json-string ??? Where is the magic happening?

Comment: let's clarify somethings...are you seeing the response body to be having your html file content and the `Content-Type` header to be `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: @KiranChalla NO, the content-type from fiddler is: Content-Type: text/html and the non-compressed html in my fiddler Raw-View are really my html tags I have created. Who is determining the content-type ?

Comment: Based on your above code, Web API actually does NOT run content-negotiation..that is, Web API does not do content-negotiation if it sees that a return type of an action is `HttpResponseMessage`...so I am kind of confused as to how you are seeing `text/html` Content-Type header...just checking, are you sharing the exact code that you have as sometimes for brevity i have seen users sharing different code in posts..

Comment: "Web API actually does NOT run content-negotiation..." That was what I thought too therefore I got confused. I have updated my init post with the missing code lines. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a while I found this explanation:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
>   Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and
>   only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

So my "browser" is inspecting the URI of the resource which ends with .HTML and therefore its treated as content-type "text/html" :-)